# Have over 200k rows in table, script takes over 20 seconds to load

Tags: php, mysql, time, pageload

I've been editing a script for a company that had this application specifically developed for their business, now they have came to me and wanted some upgrades. The entire application is in PHP and MySQL, minus a couple Python scripts to import 200k records daily to the database. My problem is that I need to allow the ability to categorize and edit notes on each record depending on it's event type. The only way to do this is by the URL embedded within each record, for it's the only truly unique value. Successfully figured this out, but now the page script takes forever (24 secs) to load.

Could someone please assist me in optimizing this bit of code?

```
$notesq = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `campaign_event_detail_v2` WHERE `call_recording_url`<>'' AND `event_type_name`='Call'") or die(mysql_error());
while($cnD = mysql_fetch_array($notesq)) {
$callid=$cnD[0];
$getD = mysql_query("SELECT campaign_notes.note, campaign_categories.category FROM campaign_notes LEFT JOIN campaign_categories ON campaign_notes.cid = campaign_categories.cid WHERE campaign_notes.cid='".$cnD['call_recording_url']."' OR campaign_categories.cid='".$cnD['call_recording_url']."'");
$getData = mysql_fetch_row($getD);
    mysql_query("UPDATE `campaign_event_detail_v2` SET `note`='".$getData[0]."',`category_id`='".$getData[1]."' WHERE `id`='".$callid."'");

}
```

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
J

Comment: Loop of Death... replace `SELECT *` with `SELECT call_recording_url`, rename `mysql_fetch_array` to `mysql_fetch_assoc` (you are duplicating fetched data with array eg `$data[0]` and `$data[id]` contain same data in two variables).

Comment: Try to avoid `SELECT *`. Check your indexes too.

Comment: I'm a little novice when it comes to building advanced MySQL queries, care to elaborate?

Comment: @user1236482: Well, it seems you only need `id` and `call_recording_url` from `campaign_event_details_v2`. So, instead of doing `SELECT * FROM ...`, you should do `SELECT id,call_recording_url FROM ...`. Also, try to make `call_recording_url` NULL if there's no data, it'll speed up the table lookup. And `event_type_name` could probably use an index.

Comment: They mean to list the columns you need instead of using *. And setup indexes on your database to speed lookups up by A LOT.

Comment: Okay, gotcha. I edited the first bit, and still have speed issues... creating the index, will that alter the table in any way that would cause malfunction of the script? I'm worried because this is an extremely complex application...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can probably manage this in a single query:

```
UPDATE campaign_event_detail_v2 d
LEFT JOIN campaign_notes n ON n.cid = d.call_recording_url
LEFT JOIN campaign_categories c ON c.cid = n.cid
SET d.note = n.note, d.category_id = c.category
WHERE d.call_recording_url != '' AND d.event_type_name = 'Call'
```

I'm not 100% sure if this is the proper logic, from what I understood it is. I must apologize if it's not. But, my point being: you can probably make it all in a single query.

You probably should add indices on columns like `event_type_name`, `category_id` and `cid`, if they're not already there. It will not affect your scripts, but will take some time to execute depending on how many records you have in your table(s).

Also, it probably would be better to use [triggers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/triggers.html) instead of executing this at each request.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you could improve this query:

```
SELECT campaign_notes.note, campaign_categories.category
FROM campaign_notes
LEFT JOIN campaign_categories
  ON campaign_notes.cid = campaign_categories.cid
WHERE campaign_notes.cid = {$cnD['call_recording_url']}
  OR campaign_categories.cid = {$cnD['call_recording_url']}
```

To this:

```
SELECT campaign_notes.note, campaign_categories.category
FROM campaign_notes
LEFT JOIN campaign_categories
  ON campaign_categories.cid = campaign_notes.cid
WHERE campaign_notes.cid = {$cnD['call_recording_url']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT campaign_notes.note, 
   campaign_categories.category 
FROM campaign_event_detail_v2 AS detail
LEFT JOIN campaign_notes ON campaign_notes.cid = detail.call_recording_url 
LEFT JOIN campaign_categories ON campaign_notes.cid = campaign_categories.cid 
          AND campaign_notes.cid = detail.call_recording_url
WHERE detail.call_recording_url<>'' 
AND detail.event_type_name='Call'
AND campaign_notes.cid IS NOT NULL -- filters any from campaign notes that are empty
AND campaign_categories.cid IS NOT NULL -- filters any from campaign categories that are empty;
```

This grabs the urls from notes and categories and filters that match the call_recording_url.  It then filters out any that didn't match in the left join (the is null check).  If that is still too slow, there are other ways of optimizing.  Then you should be able to loop through and do your update statement.

I would also try to index the ids you are joining on, especially the call_recording_url if that is a string, which takes longer to search on.

Answer (score -1):

I would create a stored procedure for this and i would create some new indexsed depend on the queryies (for example one index on: call_recording_url, event_type_name).

And -- of course -- you can create a nicer query from the two first by mixing them to only one.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind creating a stored procedure?

Comment: Peter, what would you recommend for mixing them to only one?

Comment: Stored procedures are compiled and the database server don't have to create execution plan on runtime and you don't have to access the database from PHP code 1 + 1 + many times just only once. @ITJoeNC: I don't know the exact structure of your tables.